# Why x-scroll doesn't working?

Tags: html, css

I have a trouble with x-scroll table, when I try to resize window to small size. I have the same table (with same css) which doesn't contain row with images and it works great.

HTML:

```
<div class="price_wrapper">
    <table class="price">
        <thead>
            <tr class="head">
                <th>Название</th>
                <th>Вольерная 1</th>
                <th>Вольерная 2</th>
                <th>Вольерная 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Схема</td>
                <td><img src="http://king-bitovki.ru/static/pub/img/products/budki/volyer1.jpg" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="http://king-bitovki.ru/static/pub/img/products/budki/volyer2.jpg" alt=""></td>
                <td><img src="http://king-bitovki.ru/static/pub/img/products/budki/volyer3.jpg" alt=""></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ширина</td>
                <td>90</td>
                <td>120</td>
                <td>150</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Высота</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>70</td>
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Глубина</td>
                <td>60</td>
                <td>80</td>
                <td>90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Лаз</td>
                <td>30x35</td>
                <td>39x42</td>
                <td>42x53</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Стоимость, руб.</td>
                <td>7 000</td>
                <td>9 000</td>
                <td>11 000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.price_wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
table.price {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

table.price th, 
table.price td {
    border: solid 1px #999;
    padding: 5px;
}
table.price img {
    max-width: 180px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/vasromand/gue888vp/](http://jsfiddle.net/4d20pLq5/)

Why is it?

Comment: well there is no content overflowing ...... So nothing to scroll....

Comment: Because your content is set in percentage relative to it's parent. When the content will never become larger than it's parent, you don't require a scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

You must use width for the scroll to

```
  work.price_wrapper {
      overflow-x: autol;
      overflow-y: auto;
      max-width: 400px;
      width: 100%;
 }
```

And dont use scroll because it will not be working in ie so instead you can use auto for it and set max-width or width to enable the auto scroll

Comment: While your comment about IE is correct, why would you think `max-width` as a fixed value and `width` as a percentage would work ?

Comment: If the value is less than max-width then unwantedly the space will occupy

Comment: thats not the issue here, and I think you have the wrong idea of max-width and width percentages.. EG : http://jsfiddle.net/fgh74age/

Comment: I think u have mis understood what i have told i will give u a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Your content is not overflowing, you're using the width 90% of its container.. there never will be an overflow to scroll..

800px Content

```
table.price {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

400px container

```
.price_wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
    width: 400px;
}
```

This will force the content to be wider than the wrapper.. which has the `overflow-x`

Also as correctly suggested by the other answer, use `overflow:auto`

Here is an updated version which will FORCE overflow to show you an example..

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d20pLq5/3/)

As you can see i have forced the child to be wider than its parent.. Therefore offering scroll.